# Android App does not open alert dialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I'm making an android application which requires internet connection. When I'm connected to internet, the app works fine. What I want to do is that if I'm not connected to internet, it must display an alert dialog notifying the user that it needs an internet connection. I'm using Async task to send data to server. Code for Async Task is :

```
protected class SendContacts extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{
    @Override 
    protected String doInBackground(String... str) {

        String contactInfo;
        contactInfo=str[0];

        InputStream is = null;
        String result=new String(); 

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://johnconnor.comuf.com/myphp.php");

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fullInfo", contactInfo));
           //   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat",latitude));
           //   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng",longitude));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response= httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.i("SendContacts Successful",response.getStatusLine().toString());
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent(); 

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
                        // When not connected to internet, it reach this catch block.How can i implement alert dialog here so that it can be displayed on main UI thread
            Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection:"+e.toString());

           }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } 

    result=result.substring(0,result.indexOf('\n'));
    return result ;
}

}
```

Here is my logcat:

```
08-19 14:48:15.130: D/ActivityThread(10279): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25

08-19 14:48:15.130: D/ActivityThread(10279): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608

08-19 14:48:15.130: D/ActivityThread(10279): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152

08-19 14:48:15.220: D/AbsListView(10279): Get MotionRecognitionManager

08-19 14:48:15.490: E/log_tag(10279): Error in http connection:java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "johnconnor.comuf.com": No address associated with hostname

08-19 14:48:15.500: W/dalvikvm(10279): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c66438)

08-19 14:48:15.510: W/dalvikvm(10279): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c66438)

08-19 14:48:15.510: E/AndroidRuntime(10279): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2

08-19 14:48:15.510: E/AndroidRuntime(10279): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

08-19 14:48:15.510: E/AndroidRuntime(10279):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)

08-19 14:48:15.510: E/AndroidRuntime(10279):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)

08-19 14:48:15.510: E/AndroidRuntime(10279):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)

08-19 14:48:15.510: E/AndroidRuntime(10279):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)

08-19 14:48:15.510: E/AndroidRuntime(10279):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)

08-19 14:48:15.510: E/AndroidRuntime(10279):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)

08-19 14:48:15.510: E/AndroidRuntime(10279):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)

08-19 14:48:15.510: E/AndroidRuntime(10279):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)

08-19 14:48:15.510: E/AndroidRuntime(10279):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

08-19 14:48:15.510: E/AndroidRuntime(10279): Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1

08-19 14:48:15.510: E/AndroidRuntime(10279):    at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:593)

08-19 14:48:15.510: E/AndroidRuntime(10279):    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1474)

08-19 14:48:15.510: E/AndroidRuntime(10279):    at com.example.findmyfriend.DatabaseConnection$RegisterMe.doInBackground(DatabaseConnection.java:121)

08-19 14:48:15.510: E/AndroidRuntime(10279):    at com.example.findmyfriend.DatabaseConnection$RegisterMe.doInBackground(DatabaseConnection.java:1)

08-19 14:48:15.510: E/AndroidRuntime(10279):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)

08-19 14:48:15.510: E/AndroidRuntime(10279):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)

08-19 14:48:15.510: E/AndroidRuntime(10279):    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:

**Way1:** Either you can use `runOnUIThread()` method there and have the code of alert dialog inside it. The documentation says: `It runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the current thread is the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately. If the current thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue of the UI thread.`

Eg:

```
Your_Activity_Name.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // your stuff to update the UI
                showWaitDialog();

            }
        });
```

**Way2:**
Other thing you can do ( and is preferred) is pass a `Boolean` variable to `onPostExecute`. Variable can be `true` on success and `false` in case of any failure. Then there you can show Dialog accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could override `onProgressUpdate` for `AsyncTask`, it runs on the main UI thread. Then from `doInBackground` call `publishProgress` to trigger it.

```
protected class SendContacts extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{
    AlertDialog dialog;

    public SendContacts() {
        //configure AlertDialog
        dialog = ...
    }

    @Override 
    protected String doInBackground(String... str) {

        String contactInfo;
        contactInfo=str[0];

        InputStream is = null;
        String result=new String(); 

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://johnconnor.comuf.com/myphp.php");

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fullInfo", contactInfo));
           //   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat",latitude));
           //   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng",longitude));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response= httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.i("SendContacts Successful",response.getStatusLine().toString());
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent(); 

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
                        // When not connected to internet, it reach this catch block.How can i implement alert dialog here so that it can be displayed on main UI thread
            //Update progress
            publishProgress(null);
            Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection:"+e.toString());

           }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } 

        result=result.substring(0,result.indexOf('\n'));
        return result ;
    }                               

    @Override
    //Invoked on the UI thread
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```